# how to determine whether the childNodes has <ul> present or not

Tags: javascript

how to determine whether the childNodes has  present or not: here is the code:

```
var template = "<div class="main"><p></p><ul></ul><span></span><p></p></div>"
```

within the class div I have multiple child elements. I'm getting them and storing it in nodelist like:

```
let v = new DOMParser().parseFromString(template, "text/html").body.childNodes;
```

gives me:

```
NodeList(4) [p, ul, span, p]
0: p
1: ul
2: span
3: p
```

now I want to find out which node is  node- I do this;

```
for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
//here i want to know if v contains a <ul> element- so that I can do different function.
// if(v[i]=== ul) ---- somehting like this {
    do something
}else {
          countText += v[i].textContent.length;
}
        }
```

is a there a method to kown if the childnode is ul or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Element.prototype.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

```js
for (const ul of document.querySelectorAll("ul")) {
  const hasChildLi = ul.querySelector("li") != null
  console.log(hasChildLi);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Not empty</li>
</ul>

<ul></ul>
```

Comment: I think that's the right strategy, however the OP is looking for UL, not LI. Likely the requirement is `v.querySelector('div > ul')` since they're looking for a UL that is a direct child of the div.

Answer (score 1):

use `.matches('ul')`

```js
let template = '<div class="main"><p></p><ul></ul><span></span><p></p></div>'
  , v = new DOMParser().parseFromString(template, 'text/html').body.firstChild
  ;
v.childNodes.forEach((item,i)=>
  {
  if (item.matches('ul'))
    {
    console.log(`item n°${i} is UL`)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Or just `...body.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(1) > ul')` and avoid the *forEach*. :-)

Comment: Or even `body.querySelector`, and short-circuit after the first matching example is found!